# Git branch has one name locally, a different name remotely

Tags: git

In SourceTree, I see origin/item-3667-develop item-3667-old checked in.

If I do:

```
git branch -m item-3667-old item-3667-develop
```

Will that put things right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will rename the local branch so it has the same name as the remote branch.

Note that this isn't terribly important, and you can keep working with different local and remote branches just fine, although giving them the same names might be less confusing.  (Branch tracking is a separate issue from branch names.)